# Is owning MS-Access required for .NET application to use an MS-Access db?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

Does an end-user need to own MS-Access application to run an C#.Net application that uses MS-Access? The C# custom application will ship with MS-Access File (.Accdb). The application is expected to access tables and show reports.

I expect the user to be able to download and install the run-time version of MS-Access (free) (and) OLEDB driver, then install the C# application. User may have to adjust the connection string, but I am not sure if doing just this is sufficient or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the user does not have to have the MS-Access application installed on their pc to access the db.

The only requirement is that you need to have the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable installed. You can download it here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=13255